# Is there a way to get the date of the Assembly in a Windows Phone 7 app?

Tags: c#, reflection, windows-phone-7, .net-assembly

Is there a way to get the date of the Assembly in a Windows Phone 7 app?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050396/getting-the-date-of-a-net-assembly) looked like what I am looking for, but it does not work in Windows Phone 7 due to some of the APIs missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tobias Mueller just posted a blog post on this very issue:

http://www.nextbestgeek.com/2011/04/21/version-and-compile-date-in-about-screen/