# How to know build date for C# Class libraries

Tags: c#, winforms, class, build

I'm doing C# Winform application. I have several class libraries. each library is also project. Usally, I used below code to know the build date of my application. However, I want to know build date for each class library. any help...

```
 DateTime buildDate = new 
        FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).LastWriteTime;
 MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Build Date : {0}", buildDate), "Version Info");
```

Comment: Consider searching for an answer yourself, before asking dublicate questions.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050396/getting-the-date-of-a-net-assembly

Comment: Is you question: "How to get list of all assemblies?" Or maybe "How to get assembly where given class is defined"? - very unclear...

Comment: Or you are trying to reinvent "version" assembly attribute?

Comment: @Drasive, Thanks I read poseted article already. I didn't get information what I really want.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, Thanks. I think " "How to get list of all assemblies?" is correct question. If I know all lists, then is it possible to know each build date ? right ?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**
What about this?

```
System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
DateTime lastModified = fileInfo.LastWriteTime;
```

Or you could try something as explained in the answer here:
[ASP.NET - show application build date/info at the bottom of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324245/asp-net-show-application-build-date-info-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen/324279#324279)

Comment: `file.CreationTime` is a bad idea. Just copy the file and see yourself.

Answer (score 1):

To get list of all assemblies in process use (AppDomain.CurrentDomain)[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.currentdomain.aspx] and then [AppDomain.GetAssemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx).

With the list use your code `(new FileInfo(assembly.Location).LastWriteTime;` or better yet get `Version` via [AssemblyName.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.version.aspx) by using sample from that article:

```
  Console.WriteLine("The version of the currently executing assembly is: {0}",
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version);

  Console.WriteLine("The version of mscorlib.dll is: {0}",
        typeof(String).Assembly.GetName().Version);
```